# Bigcommerce Stencil Custom Handlebars "Replace" Helper

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

Is there a syntax example for using the "replace" handlebars helper? The doc is rather vague on the practical usage. Link to doc: [here](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/custom-handlebars-helpers)

For instance:

If I had a page name of "About Us" and I wanted to replace the space with a "-".

I have tried {{replace name " " "-"}} to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

We've revised the documentation on for [handlebars.js helpers](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/v1.0/docs/custom-handlebars-helpers) to include this example:

The following code would search for the string needle within the scope defined by haystack; if found, it would replace that string with the Handlebars block defined by :

```
{{#replace "needle" haystack}}
  {{<context to use as a replacement>}}
{{/replace}}
```

Comment: Still getting an issue. When looping through pages I am printing out {{name}} successfully, but when I do a replace on {{name}} it works for the first iteration only and prints nothing for the rest of the pages.

Comment: Can you expand on how you are using it? Where is it being placed and what pages is it not showing up on?

Comment: On my homepage I am trying to loop through all of my page names in my main navigation - the end result would be to find all spaces between names and replace them with a "-". `{{#each pages}}{{#replace " " name}}{{"-"}}{{/replace}}{{/each}}`

Comment: It actually looks like the proper syntax for "replace" is: `{{#replace "needle" haystack}} <value to replace needle> {{/replace}}` The {{}} around my "-" were causing it to break. It also seems like "" are not needed for my replacement value.