# Bigcommerce Stencil bug with #replace Handlebars helper?

Tags: bigcommerce

I think there is a bug with the #replace helper where, if the "haystack" param (the input string) does not contain the "needle" param (the string to search for), the output is an empty string rather than the original string. I would expect the helper to return the original string if no match is made.

For example, this will return an empty string:

```
{{!-- where value="sometext", as in: {"value":"sometext"} --}}
{{#replace " " value}}+{{/replace}}
```

If that is the expected behavior, how can I call #replace when I don't know whether the input string will contain the value I want to replace?

Note that this example works as expected:

```
{{!-- where value="some text", as in: {"value":"some text"} 
      this correctly returns "some+text" --}}
{{#replace " " value}}+{{/replace}}
```

Comment: Check out this post and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487158/bigcommerce-stencil-custom-handlebars-replace-helper

Comment: I did see that page, but I don't think it addresses the behavior I'm seeing. I'm invoking the helper correctly, but there is no output when there is no match. I would expect the output to match the input when there is no match.

Comment: Actually, I should say I *think* I'm invoking the helper correctly. Using the syntax that's shown in the example in the docs throws an error, and using as I've shown it above works only when there is a match.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the proper usage of the #replace helper is by finding an example in the Cornerstone theme. It looks like returning an empty string when there is indeed no match is the expected behavior, and to handle the no-match case an {{else}} is needed.

So, modifying my original example, this would be the proper usage:

```
{{#replace " " value}}+{{else}}{{value}}{{/replace}}
```